Logstash Helm code for copying data from ELK to Opensearch
We were using ELK cluster for observability log monitoring in our current project and now we are moving that to opensearch tool. So we need to copy data from current ECK cluster( indices data ) to Opensearch indices.
Current Elastic search version being : V 8.8.2
Opensearch version : V 2.14.0
Currently in ECK stack, we use helm chart to push the data to elastic search , Logstash version used is 8.8.2
FOr migrating the data we are planning to build a logstash pipeline to pull data from Elasticsearch as input plugin and opensearch as output plugin.
Can help in getting correct version of logstash , to be compatible with both Elastic search and opensearch versions.
Also guide me with proper documentation to build helm chart.
